# Does Pandas.Series.unstack() affect data types?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a MultiIndex Series containing mixed-types values (timedeltas and int):

```
char   
7     a    103 minutes
      s             63
9     a    129 minutes
      s            211
10    a    106 minutes
      s             63
Name:  timestamp, dtype: object
```

Index :

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[7, 9, 10], ['a', 's']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=['char', None])
```

When I try to unstack it using `pandas.Series.unstack()`, it converts all the values to timedeltas (with a different precision):

```
    a           s
char        
7   01:43:00    00:00:00.000000
9   02:09:00    00:00:00.000000
10  01:46:00    00:00:00.000000
```

Anyone knows where this comes from?

**EDIT**

Here is a few more infos. Sample of the original data:

```
    timestamp           char
0   2008-01-15 23:56:52 7
1   2008-01-16 00:07:28 7
2   2008-01-01 16:12:32 9
3   2008-01-03 01:52:08 9
4   2008-07-06 17:23:25 10
5   2008-07-06 17:33:47 10
```

I extract a few features:

```
def get_session(ts):
    ts = ts.sort_index()
    dt = (ts - ts.shift()).fillna(0)
    first_logs = dt > '30m'
    sessions = first_logs.cumsum() + 1
    duration = sessions.value_counts().mean() * np.timedelta64(10, 'm')
    return pd.Series({'s': max(sessions), 'a': duration})

timetable = data.groupby('char')[' timestamp'].apply(get_session)
```

Which gives me:

```
char   
7     a    20 minutes
      s             1
9     a    10 minutes
      s             2
10    a    20 minutes
      s             1
Name:  timestamp, dtype: object
```

Which after being unstacked look like:

```
timetable.unstack()

a   s
char        
7   00:20:00    00:00:00.000000
9   00:10:00    00:00:00.000000
10  00:20:00    00:00:00.000000
```

Comment: can you post raw data and code to reproduce this, plus your pandas and numpy version thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like bug.

I think you can return from function `DataFrame` and then `unstack` is not necessary:

```
def get_session(ts):
    ts = ts.sort_index()
    dt = (ts - ts.shift()).fillna(0)
    first_logs = dt > '30m'
    sessions = first_logs.cumsum() + 1
    duration = sessions.value_counts().mean() * np.timedelta64(10, 'm')
    return pd.DataFrame({'s': max(sessions), 'a': duration}, index=[0])

timetable = data.groupby('char')['timestamp'].apply(get_session)
print (timetable)
              a  s
char              
7    0 00:20:00  1
9    0 00:10:00  2
10   0 00:20:00  1
```

But there is problem with index (second level are all `0`), so you can create index from column `s` and then set index `name` by [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`):

```
def get_session(ts):
    ts = ts.sort_index()
    dt = (ts - ts.shift()).fillna(0)
    first_logs = dt > '30m'
    sessions = first_logs.cumsum() + 1
    duration = sessions.value_counts().mean() * np.timedelta64(10, 'm')
    return pd.DataFrame({'a': duration}, index=[max(sessions)]).rename_axis('s')

timetable = data.groupby('char')['timestamp'].apply(get_session)
print (timetable)
              a
char s         
7    1 00:20:00
9    2 00:10:00
10   1 00:20:00
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! I used ``MultiIndex.droplevel(1)`` to drop the zeros, but your solution is shorter. Definitely something weird going on with the timedelta tough.